# How to format WPF StaticResource extension markup string value

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following code example contains the usage of WPF `StaticResource` string value:

```
<system:String x:Key="Sensor">Sensor</system:String>
...
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Sensor}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

What I need is to insert a `+` char before the "Sensor" string. (For example: `+ Senser`)

It is important to note that the usage of `TextAlignment="Center"` is necessary for me so replacing the `TextBlcok` with `Label` that uses `HorizontalContentAlignmet="Center"` is not an option, because my text is more than one line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Sensor},
                          StringFormat={}+{0}}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick and simple answer, your answer works exactly as I need!